# How to fork() an exact number of children

Tags: c, fork, children

So I'm working on a program that will do a certain task multiple times.  I've written the program once already using threads, but now I'm required to do it using processes with fork().

With threads, I'd simply create the specified number of threads, have them execute a function (changing a variable in shared memory), and then finally execute something that used the final value in shared memory.

Now however I want to do the same thing but I'm not sure how to do it as everytime I call fork() it essentially doubles itself.  So obviously if I call fork() in a forloop, each parent and child process will then go through the loop calling fork() on their own.

So my question in a nutshell:
how could I create an exact number of child processes using fork (lets say I need 5 children), and have my parent process wait until these 5 are done executing before it moves on?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Each child knows that it is the child; make sure it only does the things a child is supposed to do (go to school?) and make sure it exits without continuing where the parent process is executing (at work?).  As with the answer by niculare, or Quentin.

Answer (score 8):

I think this will work:

```
int processes = 5;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < processes; ++i) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
        // do the job specific to the child process
        ...
        // don't forget to exit from the child
        exit(0);
    }
}
// wait all child processes
int status;
for (i = 0; i < processes; ++i)
    wait(&status);
```

Comment: This works, except you'll want to call waitpid 5 times instead of just once.  waitpid(-1) means wait for "any" child process to exit, not just one.

Comment: Won't this mean that each child process will continue with the loop? For example, when `i` is 0, you spawn a child process, now the child *and* the parent both have loops and both increment `i`, both `fork` a new child process, now you have 4 processes, all increment `i`... etc. Maybe I'm wrong and I need coffee...

Comment: @dreamlax `fork()` returns 0 in the child process and the pid of the child in the parent process. The check `if (fork() == 0)` makes sure that the code in the `if` block will be executed only by the children. Since there is no `fork()` in the `if` block, the children will not create more processes.

Comment: @niculare: Now that there's an `exit(0)` in there it makes all the difference! Without it, the child process will continue looping just like its parent.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can structure your processes so that each one forks a relevant number of children (for example, the parent will fork n times, the children n-1, their children n-2, etc.), or you would limit the forks so that only the parent keep on the loop (that would be the simplest case). So make the children exit the loop.

Comment: if the children exit the loop, it means we didn't have any active children in the end?

Comment: No, the children exit the fork() loop, but continue executing normally. The parent keeps in the loop creating more children and eventually exits the loop too.